# I can't use basic expression of jinja2 in the template with django 1.9

Tags: django, python-3.x, jinja2, django-1.9

I'm using django 1.9 with jinja2, I installed the module django-jinja and I load the template well, but I can't use the basic filters of jinja2 in the template and I can't use any basic expression of jinja2.
When I try to use some basic expression of jinja2 I get the TemplateSyntaxError.

This is my setting.py with jinja2:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django_jinja",
]

from django_jinja.builtins import DEFAULT_EXTENSIONS
JINJA2_MUTE_URLRESOLVE_EXCEPTIONS = True
TEMPLATES = [
   {
        "BACKEND": "django_jinja.backend.Jinja2",
        "NAME": "jinja2",
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates/jinja2'),
        ],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "debug": True,
            'environment': 'MyApp.jinja2.environment',
            "context_processors": [
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.i18n",
                "django.template.context_processors.media",
                "django.template.context_processors.static",
                "django.template.context_processors.tz",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ], 
            "extensions": DEFAULT_EXTENSIONS + [
                'wagtail.wagtailcore.jinja2tags.core',
                'wagtail.wagtailadmin.jinja2tags.userbar',
                'wagtail.wagtailimages.jinja2tags.images',
                "django_jinja.builtins.extensions.DjangoExtraFiltersExtension",
            ]
        }
    },
]
```

My url.py Loading the template...

```
from django_jinja.views.generic.list import ListView
urlpatterns = [ 
    url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(
       model=Items,
       queryset=Items.objects.all(),
       context_object_name='items',
       template_name='jinja2/index.jinja'
    )),
]
```

My jinja2.py file

```
from __future__ import absolute_import  # Python 2 only

from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from jinja2 import Environment


def environment(**options):
    env = Environment(**options)
    env.globals.update({
        'static': staticfiles_storage.url,
        'url': reverse,
    })
    return env
```

And my index.jinja this template bring me back this error: TemplateSyntaxError at / Could not parse the remainder: '('odd', 'even')' from 'loop.cycle('odd', 'even')'

```
{% extends 'jinja2/b4.jinja' %}
{% block content %}
    <ol>
        {% for item in items %}
           <li class="{{ loop.cycle('odd', 'even') }}"><a href="#">{{ item.title|striptags }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ol>
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks in advance for the help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined a whole dictionary of settings, but you haven't actually assigned it to anything. It needs to be called `TEMPLATES` - see [the settings docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#templates).

Note I'm not sure why you've installed a third-party library, Django 1.9 includes a Jinja2 template backend.

Comment: Yes, it is defined! A mistake.